# Marquee start and stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, marquee

I want to have a marquee of pictures that scroll left and when you click on them they stop and when you click on them again they continue left. I know the marquee code, but how would you code that function in Java or jQuery?

Comment: First, don't put Java and JavaScript in the same bag, they're really different. Then, post what you have so far, or you'll get downvoted, because your question is too broad, as it's not possible to provide a specific answer.

Comment: generally speaking, you need to create a handler (function) to handle the onclick events for each of the elements. The handler should either stop the interval timer or key animation (if you've created it using css key frames)..

Comment: here is a quick fiddle demonstrating how to pause a css key animation by manipulating the class of elements (thus, using the class of an element to represent a state). http://jsfiddle.net/bcaswell/CGmCe/10875/

Comment: take the same fiddle, increase the animation **duration** and number of **'steps'**: http://jsfiddle.net/bcaswell/CGmCe/10876/

Answer (score 0):

The following demonstrates toggling the play state of a css animation to pause and play a marquee/slideshow/animation.

The animation is using the `background-position` style declaration to change the displayed position of the background image, which is the following:

[image: Several Images in a sequence]

```js
// adapted from simurai's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/

var elm = document.querySelector("div.hi");
function pause() {
    console.log(elm);
    elm.className = "hi stop";
    elm.onclick = play;
}

function play()
{
    elm.className = "hi";
    elm.onclick = pause;    
}

elm.onclick = pause;
```

```css
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
    
    -webkit-animation: play 8s steps(1000) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play 8s steps(1000) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play 8s steps(1000) infinite;
         -o-animation: play 8s steps(1000) infinite;
            animation: play 8s steps(1000) infinite;
}

.hi.stop {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}


@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
```

Comment: This evidently works which is nice that you show that it works instead of just posting some suggestion code that hasn't been tested like I've seen done to other ppl's questions so I like it for that. Unfortunatly for me it raised like 7 other questions while answering this one. So I've got a lot more to learn. I've never heard of console.log or .querySelector. So thanks for giving me new things to research.

Comment: console.log is for displaying information to the web developer tools console.. modern browsers have developer tools in the browser (although, you may have to turn a setting on - such is the case with safari) if you hit F12 in your browser it will bring up the Developer Tools.. the console will be near the bottom.. the console itself allows you to execute javascript in the window/document.. so if you have a javascript function that isn't handled or bound to an event, you can invoke it explicitly..

Comment: `<element>.querySelector`and `<element>.querySelectorAll` return non-live node lists, which means the collection/array doesn't change in size based of the **query**.. the query itself is a string in the format of CSS selectors so `document.querySelectorAll("a")` returns all `a` tags in the document as an array. `document.querySelectorAll("a > img")` returns all `img` tags that are children of `a` tags in the document.